# Constraint objects to rotate in opposite ways

Tags: rigging, constraints

I'm trying to rig an airplane's ailerons on blender. They are each near the tip of the wing and (usually) rotate in the opposite direction. I'm currently using the Locked Track to rig the other control surfaces, but is there a way to use only one control point to rotate both of them in the opposite direction?

Blend file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34207

The ailerons are the green objects. I made one, then duplicated and mirrored it to the other side (Mirror modifier wouldn't let me rotate them)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the *Invert* option:

[image]

You can select this option for any single or combination of axis.

Check out an animation made by @SixthOfFour using this technique [**here**](https://i.imgur.com/RpUlxnt.gif).

Comment: Oh, thanks... Spent so much time trying to understand how I would do this with a Locked Track and I could just copy the rotation... woah

Comment: It's a pretty nice constraint, I can't count all the times I've used it

Comment: I was working on an animated gif for my answer when yours popped in. Since my answer wasn't doing anything differently from yours, I was going to let it go, but I decided to upload the gif anyway. [Here it is](http://i.imgur.com/RpUlxnt.gif). Feel free to add it to your answer.

Comment: Thanks, added a link to it. I couldn't embed it, it was too large or something.